# NIntegrate: numerical integration not working

Tags: numerical-integration

I have the following code for a numerical integration. I don't get an error message but it gives me a clearly wrong value (it is not evaluation the integral). What do you think the problem is?

```
   Tc = 170 (* critical temprature*) ; T = 
   1.5 Tc (*temprature in that moment in terms of the critical \
   temprature*); a = 0.15  ; \[Zeta] = 1;(* \[Kappa]=1.05; *)T0 = 10.8; \
   fs = 11; b = 7; Y0 = 7.6; Z = 82 ;
   e = Sqrt[4 \[Pi]/137];
   Tf = 130 (*final temprature? (it cooles down)*);
   t0 = 0.125(* fm *);
   R = 5 (* fm *); RA = 7 (* fm *);
   \[Epsilon] = 1;
   \[Sigma] =(*0.37 (T/Tc)^2*) \[Zeta] 0.018 T /197; (* fm^-1 *)
  \[Tau] := t0/cosh[\[Eta]];
   xpf = 5 ;
  points = 2;

  i1[\[Phi]p_?NumericQ] := i2[\[Phi]p] =
   NIntegrate[ -Z*
    x ((3/2 \[Pi]*RA^3) Sqrt[
    RA^2 - x^2 + 
     b x Cos[\[Phi]p] +(*I think there was a sign problem here*)
     b^2/4])(*first part of the field*)((e^2/4 \[Pi]) Sinh[
    Y0] (xp Cos[\[Phi]] - 
     x Cos[\[Phi]p]) (\[Tau]^2 Sinh[Y0 - \[Eta]]^2 + xp^2 + x^2 - 
      2 xp x Cos[\[Phi] - \[Phi]p])^(-3/
      2) (\[Sigma] Sinh[
       Y0] Sqrt[\[Tau]^2 Sinh[Y0 - \[Eta]]^2 + xp^2 + x^2 - 
         2 xp x Cos[\[Phi] - \[Phi]p]]/2 + 
     1) Exp[\[Sigma] Sinh[Y0 - \[Eta]] Sinh[Y0] \[Tau]/
       2 - \[Sigma]/2 Sinh[
       Y0] Sqrt[\[Tau]^2 Sinh[Y0 - \[Eta]]^2 + xp^2 + x^2 - 
        2 xp x Cos[\[Phi] - \[Phi]p]]])(*second part of the \
     field*)((e^2/4 \[Pi]) Sinh[
    Y0] (xp Cos[\[Pi] - \[Phi]] - 
     x Cos[\[Phi]p]) (\[Tau]^2 Sinh[Y0 + \[Eta]]^2 + xp^2 + x^2 - 
      2 xp x Cos[\[Pi] - \[Phi] - \[Phi]p])^(-3/
      2) (\[Sigma] Sinh[
       Y0] Sqrt[\[Tau]^2 Sinh[Y0 + \[Eta]]^2 + xp^2 + x^2 - 
         2 xp x Cos[\[Pi] - \[Phi] - \[Phi]p]]/2 + 
     1) Exp[\[Sigma] Sinh[Y0 + \[Eta]] Sinh[Y0] \[Tau]/
       2 - \[Sigma]/2 Sinh[
       Y0] Sqrt[\[Tau]^2 Sinh[Y0 + \[Eta]]^2 + xp^2 + x^2 - 
        2 xp x Cos[\[Pi] - \[Phi] - \[Phi]p]]]), {x, 0, 5}];
     i3[x_?NumericQ] := 
     NIntegrate[i2[\[Phi]p], {\[Phi]p, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}];
```

Comment: How do you know the result is wrong? What result are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

That would be a lot easier to read if you were to gather repeated portions into auxiliary constants or functions. For example

```
  fun1[x_] := \[Tau]^2 Sinh[Y0 - \[Eta]]^2 + xp^2 + x^2 - 
     2 xp x Cos[\[Phi] - \[Phi]p];
  fun2[x_] := \[Tau]^2 Sinh[Y0 + \[Eta]]^2 + xp^2 + x^2 - 
     2 xp x Cos[\[Pi] - \[Phi] - \[Phi]p];
  const1 = Sinh[Y0] \[Tau]/2 - \[Sigma]/2 Sinh[Y0];
  const2 = (e^2/4 \[Pi]) Sinh[Y0];
  funMain[x_] := -Z*
    x ((3/2 \[Pi]*RA^3) Sqrt[
       RA^2 - x^2 + 
        b x Cos[\[Phi]p] +(*I think there was a sign problem here*)
        b^2/4]) (const2 (xp Cos[\[Phi]] - 
        x Cos[\[Phi]p]) (fun1[x])^(-3/
         2) (\[Sigma] Sinh[Y0] Sqrt[fun1[x]]/2 + 
        1) Exp[\[Sigma] Sinh[Y0 - \[Eta]] const1 Sqrt[
         fun1[x]]]) (const2 (xp Cos[\[Pi] - \[Phi]] - 
        x Cos[\[Phi]p]) (fun2[x])^(-3/
         2) (\[Sigma] Sinh[Y0] Sqrt[fun2[x]]/2 + 
        1) Exp[\[Sigma] Sinh[Y0 + \[Eta]] const1 Sqrt[fun2[x]]]), {x, 
   0, 5}];


i1[\[Phi]p_?NumericQ] := 
  i2[\[Phi]p] = NIntegrate[funMain[x], {x, 0, 5}];

i3[x_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[i2[\[Phi]p], {\[Phi]p, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}];
```

Other potential problems include

- You defined `i3` as a function of `x` but you didn't use `x` on the RHS, so it is a constant with respect to `x`.
- `xp` is used, but not given a value, nor treated as a variable (through pattern matching). Did you mean `x*p`? Or did you mean `xpf`, which does have a value?